# Add file link to email body VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to add a network file link to my email body using Excel VBA.

The code below add the text, but I'd like file location to be a hyperlink?

```
 strbody_2 = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b><u>" & "CapAd File:" & "</b><u>" & "<br>" _
    & Sheets("Control").Range("CapAd_File") _  ' THIS IS THE FILE LOCATION 
    & "</b></u>"
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the html `<a>`-Anchor tag:

```
strbody_2 = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri><b><u>" & "CapAd File:" & "</b><u>" & "<br>" _
    & "<a href=""" & Sheets("Control").Range("CapAd_File") & """>" _
    & Sheets("Control").Range("CapAd_File") _  ' THIS IS THE FILE LOCATION 
    & "</a></b></u>"
```

(sorry if i didn't get the apostrophies correct i didn't test it before i posted)